# AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/public

Tags: server, permissions, 22.04, apache2, php

I am running laravel project on `ubuntu` with `apache2` server and getting the below error when anyone download any invoice/shippment lebel.

The url I am accessing is https://staging.myweb.com

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.52
> (Ubuntu) Server at staging.myweb.com Port 443

error I found in my apache error.log file is

> [Sat Feb 03 11:41:30.589613 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 895124]
> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/public/: No matching
> DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated
> directory index forbidden by Options directive

Here is my virtual host file

> 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
       <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/html/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.myweb.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

> [www.staging.myweb.com-le-ssl.conf](http://www.staging.myweb.com-le-ssl.conf)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
       <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/html/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        </Directory>

CacheQuickHandler on
CacheLock on
CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
CacheLockMaxAge 5
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie

        

    CacheEnable disk /
    CacheHeader on
    CacheDefaultExpire 800
    CacheMaxExpire 64000
    CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault A300
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.myweb.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.myweb.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have added below code for testing in these VH files

```
   <Directory /var/www/html/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </Directory>
```

and htaccess files are

> root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

   

    # Rewrite to public folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

    # Rewrite to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/index\.php
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

> public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here are the permission and ownership of html
[image]

Even I have tried with the ownership change to `www-data` but no luck.

**EDIT**
if I open browser and click on disable cache then website started working fine

**EDIT-5Feb**
As I already mentioned that it is in `laravel` so there is no `index.php` in root folder. While `index.php` of `public folder is same as [this one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/index.php).

[image]

**EDIT - 7FEB**
After changing the apache log from `warn` to `debug` here are the logs

> [Wed Feb 07 09:47:56.760745 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 3362]
> mod_socache_shmcb.c(862): AH00847: insert happened at idx=1,
> data=(214:246) [Wed Feb 07 09:47:56.760750 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug]
> [pid 3362] mod_socache_shmcb.c(865): AH00848: finished insert,
> subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/2, data_pos/data_used=0/427 [Wed Feb 07
> 09:47:56.760755 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 3362]
> mod_socache_shmcb.c(530): AH00834: leaving socache_shmcb_store
> successfully [Wed Feb 07 09:47:56.760844 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug]
> [pid 3362] mod_socache_shmcb.c(508): AH00831: socache_shmcb_store
> (0x7c -> subcache 28) [Wed Feb 07 09:47:56.760853 2024]
> [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 3362] mod_socache_shmcb.c(862): AH00847:
> insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32) [Wed Feb 07 09:47:56.760858
> 2024] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 3362] mod_socache_shmcb.c(865):
> AH00848: finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1,
> data_pos/data_used=0/213 [Wed Feb 07 09:47:56.760863 2024]
> [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 3362] mod_socache_shmcb.c(530): AH00834:
> leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully [Wed Feb 07 09:47:57.014726
> 2024] [cache:debug] [pid 3371] mod_cache.c(1349): [client ] AH00769:
> cache: Caching url https://staging.myweb.com:443/index.php? for
> request /index.php, referer:
> https://staging.myweb.com/admin/sales/shipments/view/10 [Wed Feb 07
> 09:47:57.014744 2024] [cache:debug] [pid 3371] mod_cache.c(1356):
> [client ] AH00770: cache: Removing CACHE_REMOVE_URL filter., referer:
> https://staging.myweb.com/admin/sales/shipments/view/10 [Wed Feb 07
> 09:47:57.353481 2024] [cache_disk:debug] [pid 3371]
> mod_cache_disk.c(1361): [client ] AH00737: commit_entity: Headers and
> body for URL https://staging.myweb.com:443/index.php? cached.,
> referer: https://staging.myweb.com/admin/sales/shipments/view/10

After disabling the `mod_cache` and `mod_cache_disk` it started working fine. Is there anyway to fix this without disabling these `mods`

Comment: Your public folder has `Options -MultiViews -Indexes`. Why is it different from the other ones?

Comment: If I remove `Options -MultiViews -Indexes` then directory listing is shown instead of the webpage. It is in official file https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/public/.htaccess

Comment: That means the problem is not with the permissions on the html folder. The problem is that php was not installed properly. You need to make sure index.php shows your website and not the code when you type index.php in the browser. Once you've confirmed or fixed that, you would need to redirect or rewrite / to /index.php

Comment: As I mentioned that the code you mentioned in htaccess file is official. Here is my php settings
https://i.imgur.com/aC2RlIH.png

Comment: Do you have the file `index.php` or `index.html` on your html folder? If yes, what are it's contents?

Comment: I think this problem was solved by the OP disabling cache in the browser. Other people visiting the website will have a clean cache, so there will be no problem

Comment: No, it is not solved. check the update question for `index.php` content.

Comment: @DanielT it is not working the way you have mentioned. when error started it sever for all users not only for myself.

Comment: @Parto check the updated question.

Comment: "disable cache then website started working fine" means that you need to clear you browsing data or use another browser or computer. It has nothing to do with the server running on Ubuntu

Comment: But I can not clear cache of every user, also what about the error I am getting on the error.log of apache?

Comment: No, you do not need to clear the cache of every user. Right now only you have visited the website. You only need to clear the cache of people who have bad data in their cache by visiting the previous, errored version of your website. Or are you looking to prevent this problem (at the cost of higher bandwidth usage and loading time) by lowering cache timing? Then send `Cache-Control` and other headers set to 0 by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/10477326

Comment: Ok, What about the error.log error

Comment: Does this help for the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive